# Apache 2.4 <FilesMatch> Directive prevent usage of Directory Index

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have Oracle Linux 7.9 with Apache 2.4.6

I want to use Directory Index and set it in httpd.conf this way

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

It works well, but till the moment when i set next restriction

```
# Block all files by default, unless specifically allowed.
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Allow files with specifically approved file extensions
# Such as (css, htm; html; js; pdf; txt; xml; xsl; ...),
# images (gif; ico; jpeg; jpg; png; ...), multimedia
<FilesMatch "^.*\.(css|html?|js|pdf|txt|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|pl|php|json|woff|woff2|eot|svg|map)$">
Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

When I trying to browse root of my server next way http://myserver I can see next error in Apache error_log

[Mon Aug 21 15:34:47.095389 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 26127] [client 10.151.10.30:2487] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/

And only 1 record in access_log
10.151.10.30 - - [21/Aug/2023:15:34:47 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

How to fix this?

Thank you.

This recommendation is coming from CIS Security Benchmark - https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/apache_http_server

Comment: Why do you have files intended to be inaccessible to webserver uid inside your document root?

Comment: Good question. There are many files that are often left within the web server document root that could
provide an attacker with sensitive information. Most often these files are mistakenly left
behind after installation, trouble-shooting, or backing up files before editing. Regardless of
the reason for their creation, these files can still be served by Apache even when there is no
hyperlink pointing to them.